# Ajax Request is in pending state using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I'm trying to make an ajax call on click of a button... But calls are not reaching to node layer.
HTML Tag:
Show me latest mobile

app.js:

```
function postDetails() {
    $.post('/api/users', {data: 'blah'}, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
}
```

server.js

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if(req.url == '/') {
        fs.readFile("index.html", function(err, html) {
        res.end(html);
    });
    } else if(req.url.match("\.css$")) {
        var cssPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', req.url);
        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(cssPath, 'UTF-8');
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/css"});
        fileStream.pipe(res);
    } else if(req.url.match("\.js$")) {
        var cssPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', req.url);
        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(cssPath, 'UTF-8');
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/javascript"});
        fileStream.pipe(res);
    }

}).listen(8000);


app.post('/api/users', function(req, res) {
    console.log('KKKKKKKKKKuuuuuuuuuuuuuuKKKKKKK');
    router.post('/', function (req, res) {
      res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      var jsonData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
      res.status(201);
      res.json();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you are creating server and listening requests using **http**, and trying to handle routes using **app** (assuming Express object).

So either you should write routing code inside the **http.createServer's** callback function, like this -

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
  if(req.url == '/api/users' req.method === 'POST'){
    //your code here
  }
});
```

Or you should create the server using `app` (Express way)

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple handler just to verify your assumptions:

```
console.log('BEGIN');
if (req.method === 'POST' && req.url == '/api/users') {
      console.log('SUCCESS');
    }
console.log('END');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using Node / Express in a good way. If you want to make requests / responses using jQuery and Node.js, you can do it this way :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/api/users', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000, function() { console.log('App running'); });
```

The code above is a simple node.js server working with express. And below the client page index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>

</head>
<body>
  <button id="clickme">click me</button>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#clickme').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.post('/api/users', {data: 'blah'}, function (result) {
        console.log(result);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This index.html page should be in a `public` folder. You can refer to another stack overflow question to have more details : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46480598)